Can I check whether a browser already allows the user to 'see password'?
Building a site in React, and on the login screen I have the usual password fields.  I've created my own 'See Password' icon which works, but when I looked at the site in Edge rather than Chrome I realised that there's already a built-in 'eye' icon to see the password.  Is there a way to tell whether the user's browser has this feature so that I can hide my own version when it's not needed?

Yes, you can detect whether the browser has a built-in "see password" feature by checking if the password input field has a -webkit-text-security property set to disc. This property is used by some browsers (like Chrome and Edge) to hide the password by default. If this property is not set, the browser does not have a built-in "see password" feature.

Out of curiosity, may you add a [mre] HTML/CSS snippet?

@Chintan I can't see any trace of the attribute as a property on the DOM node when -webkit-text-security is present (though to be really useful as a positive detector, it'd be good if the property were always present).

@Chintan also the property can be set to other values, like "square"; I think that if there were a way to test for it at all, that'd be sufficient. edit note that I'm trying in Firefox, which does support the attribute but which does not support the little "Show the password" clickable eye.

@Chintan It's not widely supported yet MDN

@Mippy it's marked "Fully supported" on every browser that MDN tracks.

See also this question from the UX site.

@Pointy You should not rely on it for production sites, it says so on the page.
"Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

@Mippy The problem isn't the attribute, it's the behavior. Chrome shows the little clickable icon whether the attribute is present or not.  If it were possible to check the attribute, then the code could avoid rendering a home-made version of the "show password" feature. However, as noted in the comments and in other questions around, the presence of the built-in feature does not seem to be detectable.
